# Relation of entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first, code-first

These are my entities:

```
public class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Department has many employees. and every user has **just** one employee (one to one). how can i achive this relation with fluent code first?

thanx.

Comment: *Every user HAS an employee* OR *every user IS an employee*? If the latter is true, I would make Employee inherit from User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using a shared primary key, you can map it as a "One-to-Many" relationship and ignore the "Many" side.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
         .HasRequired(u => u.Employee)
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey(u => u.EmployeeId);

    }
```